# Add to a String[] another String[]

Tags: java, string, addition

```
    Info = new String[15];
    Livraison = new String[5];
    Facturation = new String[5];
    Autres = new String[3];

    Livraison = AddressForm(JP_Add_Livraison,"Livraison");
    Facturation = AddressForm(JP_Add_Facturation,"Facturation");

    Autres[0] = JT_Tel.getText();
    Autres[1] = JT_Contact.getText();
    Autres[2] = JT_Date.getText();
    Autres[3] = JT_Note.getText();

            Info.add(Livraison);
            Info.add(Facturation);
            Info.add(Autres);
```

I want the 3 String[] -> Livraison + Facturation + Autres in Info[]
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far? Also please take a look at *Java naming conventions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and array of arrays like this:

```
String[][] arrays = { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```

But, alternatively, you could create a class that has those attributes, don't know if that's what you want to do..

```
public class Something{
    String[] Livraison;
    String[] Facturation;
    String[] Autres;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think your 2nd solution is the best :p

Answer (score 2):

You'll find it much easier to do this if you work with the standard collections types. In particular, try using `List<String>`, instead of `String[]`. Then you'll find that adding mutiple lists to another list is a simple matter of calling the "addAll" method which is designed to copy the elements from one collection to another.

Answer (score 1):

[`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) will work for you.

A suggestion - how to do this!

```
int len1 = newarray.length;
int len2 = arraytobecopied.length;
String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(newarray, len1 + len2);
System.arraycopy(arraytobecopied, 0, result, len1, len2);
```

Comment: I can't its says : "Cannot invoke copy(String[]) on the array type String[]"

Comment: just this : Info.copy(Livraison);

Comment: String[] does not provide this, `Arrays` is utility class which provides the `copyOf` function

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] all = new String[15];
    String[] some = new String[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    String[] more = new String[] { "four", "five" };

    System.arraycopy(some, 0, all, 0, some.length);
    System.arraycopy(more, 0, all, some.length, more.length);

    for (String value : all) System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally over the top unless you need to do this a lot (I do) you may find wrapping the arrays in an `Iterable` useful.

```
public class JoinedArray<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  final List<T[]> joined;

  @SafeVarargs
  public JoinedArray(T[]... arrays) {
    joined = Arrays.<T[]>asList(arrays);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new JoinedIterator<>(joined);
  }

  private class JoinedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    // The iterator acrioss the arrays.
    Iterator<T[]> i;
    // The array I am working on.
    T[] a;
    // Where we are in it.
    int ai;
    // The next T to return.
    T next = null;

    private JoinedIterator(List<T[]> joined) {
      i = joined.iterator();
      a = i.hasNext() ? i.next() : null;
      ai = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (next == null) {
        // a goes to null at the end of i.
        if (a != null) {
          // End of a?
          if (ai >= a.length) {
            // Yes! Next i.
            if (i.hasNext()) {
              a = i.next();
            } else {
              // Finished.
              a = null;
            }
            ai = 0;
          }
          if (a != null) {
            next = a[ai++];
          }
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      T n = null;
      if (hasNext()) {
        // Give it to them.
        n = next;
        next = null;
      } else {
        // Not there!!
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
      return n;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }
  }

  public int copyTo(T[] to, int offset, int length) {
    int copied = 0;
    // Walk each of my arrays.
    for (T[] a : joined) {
      // All done if nothing left to copy.
      if (length <= 0) {
        break;
      }
      if (offset < a.length) {
        // Copy up to the end or to the limit, whichever is the first.
        int n = Math.min(a.length - offset, length);
        System.arraycopy(a, offset, to, copied, n);
        offset = 0;
        copied += n;
        length -= n;
      } else {
        // Skip this array completely.
        offset -= a.length;
      }
    }
    return copied;
  }

  public int copyTo(T[] to, int offset) {
    return copyTo(to, offset, to.length);
  }

  public int copyTo(T[] to) {
    return copyTo(to, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    Separator comma = new Separator(",");
    for (T[] a : joined) {
      s.append(comma.sep()).append(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
    return s.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JoinedArray<String> a = new JoinedArray<>(
            new String[]{
              "One"
            },
            new String[]{
              "Two",
              "Three",
              "Four",
              "Five"
            },
            new String[]{
              "Six",
              "Seven",
              "Eight",
              "Nine"
            });
    for (String s : a) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    String[] four = new String[4];
    int copied = a.copyTo(four, 3, 4);
    System.out.println("Copied " + copied + " = " + Arrays.toString(four));

  }
}
```

Note that the arrays are used to back the lists internally so if you change the arrays the joined versions also change. Obviously if the arrays get resized then that will break the connection.

Answer (score 0):

ask yourself question : do i really need arrays?

based on your code sample:(which actually shoulnd work as you declare length of `Autres` 3 and add 4 elements)

```
Autres[0] = JT_Tel.getText(); 
Autres[1] = JT_Contact.getText();
Autres[2] = JT_Date.getText();
Autres[3] = JT_Note.getText();
```

i recommend you to go with object Autres

```
   class Autres{
    private String tel,contact,date,note;
    //getters and setters ommited
    }
```

Comment: No, you where right I wasn't doing Object Programming. So I created 1 new class with all the field I needed and it works fine :-)